# How to make spreadsheet that converts different currencies to Euro, at a precise date exchange rate? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi everyone noob here looking for help,

I am trying to make a spreadsheet with 4 columns:
A - Date; B - Multiple Currency Values with ($,€,£); C -Exchange rate; D - B*C

In all rows depending on the symbol portraited in the cell in column B, I want the cell in column C to show the exchange rate of that currency to Euros in the date in the cell in column A, so I can then multiply the value to the exchange rate and get it in Euros.

The formula I am trying to use in Column C sure is wrong but might have something right in it, could you help me debug it please?

=IF(REGEXMATCH($B3,"£"),index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", $A3), 2, 2),
IF(REGEXMATCH($B3,"$"),index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR", "price", $A3), 2, 2),
IF(REGEXMATCH($B3,"€"),index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EUREUR", "price", $A3), 2, 2),"")))

Thanks,

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: If currency value is treated as a number then currency symbol will not be seen by regexmatch. Only if currency value is a string ($ 1000.35) regexmatch is going to find it. Please check your data format first.

Answer (score 1):

format B column as **Plain text**

[image]

use in C2 and drag down:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "£"), 
 INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", A2), 2, 2), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "\$"), 
 INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR", "price", A2), 2, 2), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "€"), 1, )))
```

[image]

use in D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*C2:C))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help player0, one question when it comes to Euros I would expect that the currencies value would stay  the same since 10 should be still 10 euros at that date. how can I keep what is doing for the $ and the £ but not change the value of the Euros?

Comment: @Ruben on a given date was € weaker compared to today' value, so back then, today's 10€ was worth of 8.15€. if you dont want to bind it to date remove A2 from GF formula

Comment: but I want to keep 1 euro as 1 euro in those cells, how do I do it?

Comment: `IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "€"), 1,"")` just set the true condition of the if statement to 1

Comment: @Ruben try: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "£"), 
 INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR", "price", A2), 2, 2), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "\$"), 
 INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR", "price", A2), 2, 2), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, "€"), 1, )))`